# Apache POI characters run for .docx

Tags: java, api, apache-poi, document, docx

In .doc files, There is a function to get each character in paragraph by using

```
 CharacterRun charrun = paragraph.getCharacterRun(k++);
```

and then I can use those character runs to inspect their attributes like

```
if ( charrun.isBold() == true) System.out.print(charrun.text());
```

or something like that. But with .docx files seems to have no characters run method that can read each word like that, I tried to use

```
XWPFParagraph item = paragraph.get(i);
List<XWPFRun> charrun = item.getRuns();
```

I found that when you call the character run in XWPF, it won't return one character to you but it will return some random-in-length strings in the document

```
XWPFRun temp = charrun.get(0);
System.out.println(temp.gettext(0));
```

This code won't return 1st character in the paragraph.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Both `.doc` and `.docx` work the same way - a CharacterRun is a sequence of characters with the same formatting applied. It could be 1 or more characters long, depending on what Word fancied doing. So, you need to nibble your way along a paragraph a run at a time, not a character at a time

Comment: Is there a way to read a character at a time? I don't know how to make it read all along the paragraph and make it stop when it's the end of paragraph.

Comment: Just fetch a paragraph, fetch all the runs in the paragraph, fetch the text of a run as a string, then nibble your way along the string via string.toCharArray() or similar?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and how can I fetch all runs in the paragraph can you show me example codes? Ps. Also I used method XWPFRun.getFontFamily() and it returned null to me what is this mean? Ps2. getFontSize also return 0 to me

Comment: Just means that the default applies. Will post code later

Comment: Also, how to avoid default value ? I just want to know what font name is and what font size is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to iterate over all the (main) paragraphs in a word document (excluding tables, headers and the like), then iterate over the character runs in that paragraph, then iterate over the text of the run one character at a time, you'd want to do something like:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("myfile.docx"));
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    int pos = 0;
    for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
        for (character c : run.text().toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println("The character at " + pos + " is " + c);
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

That will iterate over each character, and will have things like tabs and newlines represented as their character equivalents (things like `w:tab` will be converted).

For HWPF, the way of getting the paragraphs, and the way of getting the runs from a paragraph is similar but not identical, so there's no common interface. Both XWPFRun and HWPF's CharacterRun share a common interface though, so that part of the code can be re-used

Note that all text in a given [character run](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/wp/usermodel/CharacterRun.html) will share the same style / formatting information. Because of the strange ways that Word works, it's possible that two adjacent runs will also share the same styles, and Word hasn't merged them...