# Creating Numbered headings to a paragraph in word document using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

In writing to a word document using Apache poi , for the places where dynamically a paragraph has to get replicated based on some "count" , the headings for those paragraphs has to be numbered sequentially as per the section . Say if it is the 7th Section in the word document , then the headings for each paragraph in it should be numbered in 7.1 , 7.2 and so on sequentially .

Though there are certain solutions which I saw , where the xml of the word document was taken into account and  XWPFNumbering was used  .

Could there be some other easier way of doing it ?

OR

What if I have word template that already has a paragraph with a numbered heading and I have to replicate the same multiple times ? Does there exists any solution to it ?

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer to a similar problem here:
[Getting text style from docx using Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234497/getting-text-style-from-docx-using-apache-poi/49502339#49502339)

I used the same approach to copy the header numbering format from one document to another. Copy numbering.xml from your source document to your new output document.

```
// copy an existing numbering.xml document into this document to give multilevel headings
public void copyNumbering(String numberingXmlString) {
    try {
        CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(numberingXmlString);
        XWPFNumbering numbering = getDoc().createNumbering();
        numbering.setNumbering(cTNumbering);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e, e);
    }
}
```